# Add captions to two graphs side by side

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

How do I add a caption under each graph while still keeping them next to each other?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{main node/.style={circle,fill=black,draw,minimum size=.2cm,inner sep=0pt},}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[main node, label=above:{$a$},] (1) {};
            \node[main node, label=right:{$b$}] (2) [below right = 1cm and 1cm of 1] {};
            \node[main node, label=left:{$c$}] (3) [below left = 1cm and 1cm of 1] {};

            \path[draw, thick]
            (1) edge node {} (2)
            (2) edge node {} (3)
            (1) edge node {} (3);
        \end{tikzpicture} \hspace{2cm}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[main node, label=left:{$a$},] (1) {};
            \node[main node, label=left:{$b$}] (2) [below = 1cm of 1] {};
            \node[main node, label=right:{$c$}] (3) [right = 1cm of 1] {};
            \node[main node, label=right:{$d$}] (4) [below = 1 cm of 3] {};

            \path[draw, thick]
            (1) edge node {} (2)
            (2) edge node {} (4)
            (3) edge node {} (4)
            (1) edge node {} (3);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A proper numbered caption, or just some text? If proper caption, subcaptions (Fig 1a and 1b, with main caption below), or two separate figures (Fig 1 and Fig 2)?

Comment: I would just like some text under each graph without a main caption.

Comment: For two figure captions use two minpages with a caption in each.  The width of the minipage determines the width of the caption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways of achieving this. For no captions at all, you could use M S' answer, but not using a `figure` environment, using `minipage` instead of `subfigure`, and just writing the text directly after `\end{tikzpicture}`, no `\caption`. Add an empty line (paragraph break) before the text though.

Here I show a completely different approach, with a single `tikzpicture`, and the second diagram moved to the right with `\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm, local bounding box=b]`. The `local bounding box` creates a node that fits around the content of the `scope`, which I use to position a `\node` with the text.

Another detail: in general don't use `\usetikzlibrary{..}` after `\begin{document}`. Doesn't seem to cause a problem here, but I've seen cases where it doesn't work, so better to load libraries in the preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{main node/.style={circle,fill=black,draw,minimum size=.2cm,inner sep=0pt},}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
            captiontext/.style={below=3mm, text width=5cm}
            ]
            \node[main node, label=above:{$a$}] (1) {};
            \node[main node, label=right:{$b$}, below right = 1cm and 1cm of 1] (2)  {};
            \node[main node, label=left:{$c$}, below left = 1cm and 1cm of 1] (3) {};

            \draw [thick] (1) -- (2) -- (3) -- (1);
            
            \node [captiontext] at (current bounding box.south) {Text text and more text ad infinitum and so on.};


        \begin{scope}[xshift=5cm, local bounding box=b]
            \node[main node, label=left:{$a$},] (1) {};
            \node[main node, label=left:{$b$},below = 1cm of 1] (2)  {};
            \node[main node, label=right:{$c$}, right = 1cm of 1] (3)  {};
            \node[main node, label=right:{$d$}, below = 1 cm of 3] (4)  {};

            \draw [thick] (1) -- (2) -- (4) -- (3) -- (1);
            \end{scope}
            
            \node [captiontext] at (b.south) {More text text and more text ad infinitum and so on going on for a bit.};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two side-by-side minipages. The problem to solve is to make the captions to appear at the same level even if the pictures and the captions have different vertical size.

My solution is to embed the pictures in nested minipages with bottom alignment. The outer minipages instead have top alignment, which actually means that their reference points will be the ones of the top box, thus the bottom of the picture. This will place the captions at the same vertical position on the page.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
  main node/.style={
    circle,
    fill=black,
    draw,
    minimum size=.2cm,
    inner sep=0pt
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
% left column
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[main node, label=above:{$a$},] (1) {};
    \node[main node, label=right:{$b$}] (2) [below right = 1cm and 1cm of 1] {};
    \node[main node, label=left:{$c$}] (3) [below left = 1cm and 1cm of 1] {};

    \path[draw, thick]
      (1) edge node {} (2)
      (2) edge node {} (3)
      (1) edge node {} (3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{minipage}

  \caption{This is the figure on the left, with a not so lengthy caption}
\end{minipage}\hfill % <--- don't forget
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
% right column
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[main node, label=left:{$a$},] (1) {};
    \node[main node, label=left:{$b$}] (2) [below = 1cm of 1] {};
    \node[main node, label=right:{$c$}] (3) [right = 1cm of 1] {};
    \node[main node, label=right:{$d$}] (4) [below = 1 cm of 3] {};

    \path[draw, thick]
      (1) edge node {} (2)
      (2) edge node {} (4)
      (3) edge node {} (4)
      (1) edge node {} (3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{minipage}

  \caption{This is the figure on the right, with a long caption,
    that should form at least three lines; we add text so that
    it's long enough}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below mentioned code serves your purpose. It basically a single figure with two sub captions. If you need two different figures with captions please let me know.

Based on your recent comment. You can comment the main figure caption part.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,subcaption}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{main node/.style={circle,fill=black,draw,minimum size=.2cm,inner sep=0pt},}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[main node, label=above:{$a$},] (1) {};
        \node[main node, label=right:{$b$}] (2) [below right = 1cm and 1cm of 1] {};
        \node[main node, label=left:{$c$}] (3) [below left = 1cm and 1cm of 1] {};
        \path[draw, thick]
        (1) edge node {} (2)
        (2) edge node {} (3)
        (1) edge node {} (3);
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \caption{caption1} \label{fig:M1} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
        \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[main node, label=left:{$a$},] (1) {};
        \node[main node, label=left:{$b$}] (2) [below = 1cm of 1] {};
        \node[main node, label=right:{$c$}] (3) [right = 1cm of 1] {};
        \node[main node, label=right:{$d$}] (4) [below = 1 cm of 3] {};
        \path[draw, thick]
        (1) edge node {} (2)
        (2) edge node {} (4)
        (3) edge node {} (4)
        (1) edge node {} (3);
    \end{tikzpicture}  
\caption{caption2} \label{fig:M2}  
\end{subfigure}
\caption{main caption}  
\end{figure}   
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]